# Jquery Load() returns [object object] when fetch element id value from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm fetching value from mysql query result page.php into display.html. I'm able to show "VALUE368" value in display.html in div ID.
but I also want to log "VALUE386" in firebase realtime database, for that I'm trying with below code.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  function testing(){
    return $('#VALUE368').load('data.php #VALUE368');
    //return 100 + 300 ;
  } 
  var tag1 = testing();
  document.write(JSON.stringify(tag1));
  console.log(tag1);
});
```

I also tried with 
`var tag1 = document.getElementById("VALUE386");`
 but it returns null value.

Please help me in that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `load()` returns a jQuery object which contains the `#VALUE368` element. This is why you see `[object Object]` when you call `stringify()`.

Aside from that, your logic is very odd. You're calling `document.write` (which itself is bad practice) in an attempt to write content to the DOM which `load()` will already have done for you.

You can simply change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#VALUE368').load('data.php #VALUE368');
});
```

Comment: yes you are right. using your code I'm able to display VALUE368 on html page. but the main problem is to log same value in firebase db. I'm not able to do that. how can I assign value of "VALUE368" to a variable. so that variable can be logged in firebase. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `load()` callback to read the value you just set from the `div` you put it in, although if you're only getting a single value it would make far more sense to make a normal AJAX request to return just that. You would need to modify your PHP code in order to do that. I'd suggest starting a new question about that specific goal if you want to do it that way, but make sure you include all relevant PHP code.

Comment: `var tag1 = $(' #VALUE370').text(); `  ;-) Its working.. can I use load() to fetch text (not html)  from second page div.